# Adding colour on top of an image

Tags: html, css

Although very similar questions have been answered, none satisfy exactly what I need.

When adding colour on top of the picture, the colour just covers the full page. Any idea's on how to add colour ONLY onto the picture, and leave the rest of the page the untouched?

```css
.section {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  background-image: url('https://geology.com/world/the-united-states-of-america-map.gif');
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

.section:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</div>


<div class="section">
  <h1> Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding `position: relative` to the `.section`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `position: absolute` to work as you expect, the element's parent needs to be positioned.

> A positioned element is an element whose computed position value is either relative, absolute, fixed, or sticky. (In other words, it's anything except static.) [Position - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
.section {
  background-image: url('https://geology.com/world/the-united-states-of-america-map.gif');
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</div>


<div class="section">
  <h1> Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: 50% there - the issue is, the colour doesn't take the border-radius into account, so it's covering more than just the image.

Comment: @DukeDodson Add overflow hidden too

Answer (score 0):

```css
.section {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  background-image: url('https://geology.com/world/the-united-states-of-america-map.gif');
  margin-top:100px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.section:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
    border-top-left-radius: 50% 20%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50% 20%;
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</div>


<div class="section">
  <h1> Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest an absolute positioned element in your section. The section then hast to be position: relative, like so:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="color"></div>
  <h1> Hello</h1>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.section {
  position: relative
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  background-image: url('https://geology.com/world/the-united-states-of-america-map.gif');
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

.color {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 20%;
  background: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
}
```